# How to reinstall ProjectUITests after deleting?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, target

I know this may sound stupid, but I accidentally deleted my UITests target from my project. The folder "FifteenUITests" is still there with the proper files, but I get two errors. How can I reinstall my UITests target onto my project? The exact errors I get are below.

Error: 'FirebaseAuthInterop/FIRAuthInterop.h' file not found

Error in Terminal: [!] Unable to find a target named `FifteenUITests`, did find `Fifteen`.

Comment: @matt How can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the project and make a new test target by clicking the + button under the target list. Choose which kind of test target you want.

[image]

[image]

The original files are probably still there, so then just drag them from the project folder into the project navigator and make them part of the test target.